# Add custom attributes to table rendered by WebGrid

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid

I am using an MVC3 WebGrid, and want to add custom attributes of the form "data-xxx" to the `<table>` element rendered by `WebGrid.GetHtml()`.

I tried to do this as follows:

```
grid.GetHtml(...
    htmlAttributes: new { data_xxx = "value" }
);
```

However this renders as:

```
<table ... data_xxx="value">
```

instead of the expected:

```
<table ... data-xxx="value">
```

I.e. unlike other MVC helpers, it doesn't replace the underscore in the property name with a hyphen.

After a bit of spelunking with Reflector it seems that:

1. `WebGrid.GetHtml()` calls `System.Web.WebPages.Html.ObjectToDictionary` to convert the anonymous attributes object to a dictionary.  Unlike the method `System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes` used by other helpers, this doesn't replace "_" by "-".
2. Unlike most other MVC helpers, `WebGrid.GetHtml()` does not have an overload that takes an `IDictionary<string, object>`, so I can't work around the bug by specifying the attributes in this way.

This looks like a bug to me, and I've submitted it to Connect:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/767456/webgrid-gethtml-helper-does-not-allow-data-attributes-to-be-set

Any suggestions for a workaround?  Or is it fixed in MVC4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this issue:

This was fixed yesterday in CodePlex by resolving issues 610 & 575.

https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/610

https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/575

You can try out the [nightly bits](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Use%20Nightly%20Builds).