# Adding HTML5 data attributes to System.Web.Helpers.WebGrid

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4, webgrid, razor-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add custom attributes to table rendered by WebGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12900138/add-custom-attributes-to-table-rendered-by-webgrid)

How can I add HTML5 data attributes to an instance of `System.Web.Helpers.WebGrid`? I read that using an anonymous object whose attributes has an underscore (`_`) will be replaced by dashes (`-`).

But it doesn't seems to work. I have the following code in ASP.NET MVC4 using Razor 2.

```
@{
  var grid = new WebGrid(Model);
  @grid.GetHtml(htmlAttributes: new { data_feature: "selectable" });
}
```

And it render as:

```
<table data_feature="selectable">...
```

It should render as (with dash instead of underscore):

```
<table data-feature="selectable">...
```

Is it a known bug? Is it possible to add HTML5 data attribute to a `WebGrid`?

Comment: There is a registered bug for this: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/767456/webgrid-gethtml-helper-does-not-allow-data-attributes-to-be-set